# Is it possible to catch a segfault with try/catch?

Tags: c++, try-catch

I did this test to see what happened:

```
try
{
    int *x = 0;
    *x = 1234;
}
catch(...)
{
    cout << "OK";
}
```

But it throws a segfault, why does it not catch the segfault?

Comment: A segfault is signal not an exception?

Comment: @cheroky _"A segfault is signal not an exception?"_ Yes.

Comment: Someone can compile and run with Visual C++ without get segfault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can`t.

A `SEGFAULT` isn't a regular exception.

The code you show is simply undefined behavior, and anything may be happen. There's no guarantee it ends up throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is very specific to WINDOWS.**

You can use Structured Exception Handling.

You have to call "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx

usage prototype:

You have to register a function at the beginning of application

```
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledExceptionFilterFunction);
```

Define your registered function, Handle your business. 
Usually people collect coredumps and send Emails to dev team.

```
LONG WINAPI UnhandledExceptionFilterFunction(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS exception)
{


// The exception information is available in  PEXCEPTION_POINTERS 

}
```

Refer below link for PEXCEPTION_POINTERS 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679331(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is the list of exception records that you get in "PEXCEPTION_POINTERS". The first one is "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" (in LINUX terms SEGFAULT)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I can't see how that question is specific to windows.

Comment: I agree. Question is not specific to windows. That's why  I mentioned very first in my answer. But may help any windows programmer who comes to this page.

Comment: It also may trigger people thinking about, why can not on LINUX or UNIX like systems.